# How to stop the image at a specific pixel?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How do I stop a moving image at a specific pixel?
Kinda new to javascript

Been trying to use if-else, not sure if i enter the code correctly.

```
var imgObj = null;
var animate ;
function init(){
   imgObj = document.getElementById('xTank');
   imgObj.style.position= 'relative'; 
   imgObj.style.left = '0px'; 
}

function moveRight()
{
    if(imgObj<400){
        imgObj.style.left = parseInt(imgObj.style.left) + 10 + 'px';
        animate = setTimeout(moveRight,70); // call moveRight in 20msec
       }
    else
       {
        stopanimate = setTimeout(moveRight,70);
       }
}

window.onload =init;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check for the left style value, not the image object itself:

```
function moveRight()
{
    if(parseInt(imgObj.style.left, 10) < 400){
        imgObj.style.left = parseInt(imgObj.style.left, 10) + 10 + 'px';
        setTimeout(moveRight,70); // call moveRight in 20msec
       }
    else
       {
        //stopanimate = setTimeout(moveRight,70); // no need to animate it anymore
       }
}
```

Also, don't forget to call your moveRight function at some point.

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/shomz/gj3Sa/